# BlackBerry Image Field fill screen horizontally

Tags: image, blackberry, bitmap

I am new to BlackBerry Development (5.0). I have a little experience in Android Applications Development. 
What I'm trying to do is fill an image on the whole screen (Horizontally) 
Similar to what you could do in Android using `fill_parent` in a layout file.
I've looked on some forums to find a solution, but didn't get a satisfactory one.

This is how I'm getting my image

```java
Bitmap headerLogo = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("uperlogo.png");
BitmapField headerLogoField = 
    new BitmapField(headerLogo, BitmapField.USE_ALL_WIDTH | Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
setTitle(headerLogoField);
```

This code is giving me my header on top (as required) and in the center. I simply want this to stretch horizontally to cover all space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to stretch the `Bitmap` horizontally before creating the `BitmapField`, and that will solve the problem. But stretching `Bitmap` and using it as title will create problem for devices that supports screen rotation (e.g. Storm, Torch series). In that case you have to maintain two stretched `Bitmap` instance, one for the portrait mode and other for landscape mode. And you also need to write some extra code for setting the appropriate `Bitmap` depending on the orientation. If you don't want to do that then check following 2 approaches:

***Using CustomBitmapField instance***

A CustomBitmapField that can stretch `Bitmap` horizontally can be used. Check the implementation.

```java
class MyScreen extends MainScreen {

    public MyScreen() {
        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("uperlogo.png");
        setTitle(new CustomBitmapField(bm));
    }

    class CustomBitmapField extends Field {
        private Bitmap bmOriginal;
        private Bitmap bm;

        private int bmHeight;

        public CustomBitmapField(Bitmap bm) {
            this.bmOriginal = bm;
            this.bmHeight = bm.getHeight();
        }

        protected void layout(int width, int height) {
            bm = new Bitmap(width, bmHeight);
            bmOriginal.scaleInto(bm, Bitmap.FILTER_BILINEAR);
            setExtent(width, bmHeight);
        }

        protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
            graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bmHeight, bm, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

***Using Background instance***

`Background` object can solve the problem easily. If a `Background` instance can be set to a `HorizontalFieldManager` which will use all the width available to its, then in case of screen rotation it will take care of its size and background painting. And the `Background` instance will itself take care of the streching of the supplied `Bitmap`. Check the following code.

```java
class MyScreen extends MainScreen {

    public MyScreen() {
        setTitle(getMyTitle());         
    }

    private Field getMyTitle() {
        // Logo.
        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("uperlogo.png");

        // Create a manager that contains only a dummy field that doesn't 
        // paint anything and has same height as the logo. Background of the 
        // manager will serve as the title.

        HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH);
        Background bg = BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(bm, Background.POSITION_X_LEFT, Background.POSITION_Y_TOP, Background.REPEAT_SCALE_TO_FIT);
        hfm.setBackground(bg);
        hfm.add(new DummyField(bm.getHeight()));

        return hfm;
    }

    // Implementation of a dummy field
    class DummyField extends Field {
        private int logoHeight;

        public DummyField(int height) {
            logoHeight = height;
        }

        protected void layout(int width, int height) {
            setExtent(1, logoHeight);
        }

        protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The "Using Background Instance" implementation solved my problem. Thanks a bunch :)